# Skewness and kurtosis

Tags: data-cleaning

Should skewness and kurtosis calculations be done before or after train-test split? Are there any implications of doing it before/ after train-test split?

Comment: What will you use their values for?

Comment: to meet logistic regression assumption

Comment: I don't think kurtosis or skewness can help you verify logistic regression assumptions. However, I provided an answer in general for "model selection purposes"

Comment: That you want to satisfy skewness and kurtosis assumptions to run a logistic regression tells me that you have a misconception about logistic regression. What skewness and kurtosis assumptions do you think you have to meet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute statistics for model selection, then you should do it on the training data, after performing the train-test split.